# Ip to geolocation conversion like maxmind geoip

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I am looking some more or less precise solution to resolve german ip's to geograpical locations with city precision. But I have suddenly found that geoip lite has no city data for most of german IPS - only ISP and Land.

Is there exists some other provider for it ? 
I don't need very precise solution but something better than nothing for Europa and specially for Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oleg, you can consider the free [IP2Location LITE](https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city) which covers German IP addresses. You can see the list of German IP address breakdown as below.

https://lite.ip2location.com/germany-ip-address-ranges